# The minimax problem : $ \min \max \cos(d_i - d_j)$

Tags: calculus

I am looking for an analytic solution to the following problem for fixed $N\in\Bbb N$:
$$ \min_{\{d_i\}_{i=1}^N\subset \Bbb R} \max_{\substack{1\leq i,j\leq N\\ i \neq j}} \cos(d_i - d_j)$$

After hours of playing with it, I realized that for $2 \leq N \leq 7$ the solution is
$$\{d_i\} = \{0, 2\pi/N, 4\pi/N, \cdots, 2(N-1)\pi/N\}$$
However, I am still looking for a proof!

Comment: @Surb Thanks. No, I didn't mean that.

Answer (score 1):

The cosines depend only on the $d_i\pmod{2\pi}$, hence we can identify $d_i$ with $e^{id_i}\in S^1$, and then $\cos(d_i-d_j)$ is a decreasing function of the angle between $e^{id_i}$ and $e^{id_j}$. Thus we want to pplace $N$ points on $S^1$ such thatclose points are avoided, i.e., the shortest distance (which happens between adjacent points) should be maximized. Quite obviously, the extremal case is when the points are placed at the vertices of a regular $n$-gon. Thus the general conjecture evolving from your observation is correct, the min-max equals $\cos\frac{2\pi}N$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to use your answer as a proof in a scientific article?

Comment: @MahdiKhosraviIn a scientific article I might condense my proof to athe single word "clearly" ;)